# Did practice users have salesforce license

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, force.com

I am trying to create the user(ex
: Kandhimalla) and I want to assign one profile to that user which I have created(Professor).

For that profile, a user license is salesforce while I am creating. Whereas when I went to create user(Kandhimalla) and am trying to assign profile(Professor) to that user, In the User license pick list it is not showing "salesforce" license it is showing "salesforce platform", by this I cannot able to see the profiles which I have created. I have attached screenshots regarding this issue.

See here, I am not able to see salesforce option:
[image: see here, I am not able to see salesforce option].

Answer (score 0):

You probably reached the salesforce Licenses limit in your env.

Check the limit by going to **Setup->Company Profile->Company Information** and check the **Total Licenses** and **Used Licenses**